# how to get the padding left value of a< tr> content which is get as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
//for table//
function tabledata() {
        var body = document.body,
                 tbl = document.createElement('table'),
                 tableId = document.createAttribute('id');
        tableId.value = "tabledata";
        tbl.setAttributeNode(tableId);
        tbl.style.width = '100%';

        tbl.style.borderCollapse = 'collapse';

        for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            var tr = tbl.insertRow();
            tr.setAttribute("data-id", i, 0);
            for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

                var td = tr.insertCell();
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));


            }

        }

        // $(".lefttablediv").append(tbl);

        $(".tablediv").append(tbl);

    };
    tabledata();


    $('#tabledata').editableTableWidget();

//for on click//
    $("#indent").click(function () {
         var CurrentTrId = $("tr.selected").attr("data-id"); 

        var ParrentTrId = (CurrentTrId) - 1; 

        if( ParrentTrId == 0)
        {
            return
        }

        var CurrentTrLeftValue = parseInt($(".selected > td:first-child").css("padding-left"));

        var parrentTrLeftValue =parseInt($('#' + ParrentTrId).css('padding-left')); alert(parrentTrLeftValue)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

hi i want know my parent tr padding left value and also i want to add a class for it. i got parent tr id in variable like this way

```
var CurrentTrId = $("tr.selected").attr("data-id");
var ParrentTrId = (CurrentTrId) - 1;
```

i want to know the left value of  parent tr content when i clicked on a button
my doubt is how i add a class for a tr which is got from a variable

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: my doubt is how i get the ParrentTrId.paddingleft value()

Comment: Try `$('#'+ParrentTrId).css('padding-left')`

Comment: @Rayon I USE THIS code but why it show the result is undefined

Comment: You have not shared complete code yet.. How will one provide the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to write Rayon's code like this. 
`$('#',ParrentTrId).addClass('blabla').`

However if the parent has an attribute id value and if that is different that the data-id value. Either way I think a better way to do this would be.

```
$('.selected').parent().addClass('addMyClass');
```

It is straight forward and seems to be what you are wanting to do.